# Button with Minim/Processing to play sound

Tags: arduino

I have been trying to play a sound on my laptop by pressing a homemade button on my Arduino.

Now I found this [example code](https://gist.github.com/4215212) to play a file with Minim.

I want to know where I can trigger the button in the code, to play the sound.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: When the button is pressed, the Arduino warns the Processing via serial communication. Where is your Arduino code?

Answer (score 0):

Try By looking here [Arduino and Processing](http://playground.arduino.cc//Interfacing/Processing)
This page explains communication examples and how to communicate between arduino and processing

And then you just need to call "player.play();"(from the example you need to remove it)
once the user presses the button